# Excel: Use conditional formatting to color cell with two colors based on two variables within same cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet with a row where I list people's names. Each person has a different color assigned to each name. However, sometimes I have to put two names in a single cell. I'd like the colors to remain consistent, and excel has features where colors can fade in and out on a gradient.

If Bob is blue and Alice is green, and I type 'Bob' in the cell, the cell turns blue. Great! What I want is for the cell to turn half blue half green when I type 'Bob & Alice' in the cell.

Is there a way to do this without resorting to VBA? Since it's for a work project, I don't want to rely on a coding system I don't entirely understand.

Comment: What about two separate cells, formatted to look like one?

Comment: Wouldn't work for my purposes. But thanks for the finality, lmao, I was worried I was missing something. *Is* it possible to do with VBA?

Comment: No, it is not possible with vba.  You can assign only one color to the cell.

Comment: The closest I would think you could do is to use conditional formatting to fill the cell with one color and a pattern on that cell with another color, but depending on your data, this could get overwhelming quickly and would likely look atrocious to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA this is possible using one Conditional Formatting rule for each single name and for each name combination.

Example:

[image]
[image]

Conditional formatting rules are:

Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Formulas:

Rule 1: `=AND(SEARCH("bob",$A1)>SEARCH("alice",$A1))`

Rule 2: `=AND(SEARCH("bob",$A1)<SEARCH("alice",$A1))`

Rule 3: `=SEARCH("alice",$A1)`

Rule 4: `=SEARCH("bob",$A1)`

**The order and the checked "Stop If True" is important.**

To set the fill effects in **Format** - **Fill** click the button **[Fill Effects]** below the table of the background colors:

[image]

Using `VBA` this could be achieved more flexible. If you are interested in a `VBA` solution, then please edit your question and mention this there and put the `excel-vba` tag to the question.

Comment: @pnuts: Yes a lot of rules and much more rules if you wants to make this general usable for all possible pairs. That's why I wrote "Using VBA this could be achieved more flexible." But the question is not about using VBA - until now.