# How to combine 2 rules and change the fill color

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting, rules

I'm trying to combine 2 rules and their fill colors.
I'm using

```
    =ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Words",$A1))
```

applied to

```
    =$1:$100000
```

for the initial rule/set of rules in my sheet.

I want to combine 2 rules like this into a singular rule and change the fill.

Something like, if rule1 and rule2 are present - change the fill to this(whatever fill would be at this point)

I am attaching an image with the product of 2 rules and with an example of what I would like to happen. I'll even take a longer version. I just didn't want to write out the same thing over 15 times for my desired results.

[image: rule1,2&desiredresult]

Comment: Do you have a limited set of combinations? Then you could define a rule for each of them (or assign a value in a separate column that you then reference)? But I guess you have quite a few combinations so you need excel to mix the formatting for you?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944925/excel-use-conditional-formatting-to-color-cell-with-two-colors-based-on-two-var) could be helpful - if you are looking for a non-vba solution this works for your purpose. Otherwise you will need to use vba.